# Debug malformed json data from recaptcha response?

Tags: php, json, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha with ajax and all data posted is working fine.

There is a problem decoding the response into json.

When echoing the recaptcha response from Google I get error code 4 from `json_last_error()` meaning the syntax of the json is incorrect and it can't be decoded.

How / where do I get the json response so I can debug it? `var_dump($responseKeys)` gives me null and `$response` gives me 1.

Note that the recaptcha is working normally, just having issues with decoding the response for use with validation.

Error

Could not decode JSON! Malformed JSON`

Recaptcha

```
$ch = curl_init();

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//read post content
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

//turns json string into php var $obj
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

//retrieve captcha response
$captcha = $obj["captchaResponse"];

//create captchaResponse instance
$captcha;

//KEYS
//prod 
//$secretKey = 'xxx';

//localhost
$secretKey = "xxx";

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    //$timeout = 5;
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        "secret" => $secretKey,
        "response" => $captcha,
        "remoteip" => $ip
    ],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);

//get response from recaptcha
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

if(intval($responseKeys['success']) !== 1) {

        //debuggingRECAPTCHA RESPONSE
        echo  'var_dump' , var_dump($responseKeys);

        echo  '$jsonError ' , $jsonError;

    }`
```

When I echo `$responseKeys` I get nothing and 'print_r($responseKeys)' gives me `1`.

I was wondering how I can get the (edit: json) output of `$response` to get some indication of what is wrong.

Any other ways to debug it?

Ready to add more info if requested.

Thanks.

Edit: Added more info to clarify based on comments.

Comment: "I was wondering how I can get the output of $response"....`print_r($response);`??? Did I miss something? BTW I seriously doubt Google is giving you bad JSON, although I suppose it's potentially possible. I'd guess the most likely thing is it isn't actually JSON, or a small chance you're somehow decoding it incorrectly. Also `echo  '$jsonError ' , $jsonError;`....where is $jsonError coming from in your code? It appears to be undefined.

Comment: Well @JPB ? Have you done `print_r($response);` right after the `$response = curl_exec($ch);` call? What does it output?

Comment: I need the decoded json output of $response as per the question. $response just outputs `1`. $jsonError is a function based on json_last_error()'s error code.

Comment: The problem must be somewhere on your end. Most likely somewhere between `curl_init` and `curl_setopt`. Because even if you use some garbage as data and post it to Google you get some proper JSON response: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/fdyd-v3hb

Comment: @MarioWerner thanks for that it was helpful.

Comment: @JPB what is the content type returned by server (you can find by enabling CURLOPT_HEADER => true). Does it return `application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours banging my head against the wall @MarioWerners's comment proved the code was working fine so I began looking at my environment. Because I am developing locally Google was rejecting the request so I had to add.

//dev only

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOSTM => false`

and now the request is accepted.

In hindsight I should have added the environment into the question. My apologies.